# Failed to fetch when registering an existing component

Tags: backstage

I'm following the official Getting Started instructions and got Backstage up and running with PostgreSQL backend and GitHub authentication. But when I get to [the step to register an existing component](https://backstage.io/docs/getting-started/configuration#register-an-existing-component), I get the following error message when I click the `Analyze` button:

> Failed to fetch

[Backstage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMJvw.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because your App does not have permission to integrate with a repository from the Backstage organization.

My sugestion:

1. Create a testing organization (local environment).
2. Create at least one "team" in this organization.
3. Create at least one repository with the configuration file `catalog-info.yaml`
4. Create another repository, without the configuration file, so that you can successfully replicate the test.

Hope this helps.